# Is my proof about square roots of complex numbers well-written?

Tags: complex-numbers, proof-writing

I wanted to prove that for any complex number $a+bi$ where $b=\Im(a+bi)\neq 0$, there does not exist a real number $c$ such that $\sqrt{a+bi}=c$. (Or simply put, that the square root of a non-real number never yields a real number).

I am very new to proof writing and I might skip some steps or maybe sometimes add unnecessary things to the proof, that's why I am asking, **is this proof well-written?:**

> Suppose that there exists a real number $c$ and a complex number $a+bi$, where $b\neq 0$ and $c\neq 0$, such that $\sqrt{a+bi}=c$. It follows that
>
> $$a+bi=c^2;$$
> $$\text{Hence,}\,\, bi=c^2-a.$$
>
> Since $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then $c^2\in\mathbb{R}$, and it can be observed that $a=\Re(a+bi)\in\mathbb{R}$; hence $c^2-a\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, $bi\notin\mathbb{R}$, and since $bi=c^2-a$, then it follows that $c^2-a\notin\mathbb{R}$. But previously it was stated that $c^2-a\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, a contradiction has been reached.

Comment: For completeness (to be pedantic) you should probably state explicitly that $a$ and $b$ are assumed to be real.

Comment: @Bungo got it, thanks for feedback :)

Comment: It's very well-written. While we're being pedantic, I would make note of the fact that $bi\ne \mathbb R$ is a consequence of the fact that $b\ne 0.$ Just to match the level of detail you've given to other things.

Comment: If $c \in \mathbb R$ then $c^2 = a+bi \in \mathbb R$ and $\Im(a+bi) = 0$.  That's all.  Don't go any further.  (Unless you want to prove that multiplication is closed in the Reals.... which is really beyond the pale.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose that there exists a real number $c$ and a complex number
>   $a+bi$, where $b≠0$ and $c≠0$, such that $\sqrt{a+bi} = c$. . It
>   follows that
>
> $a+bi=c^2$;
>
> Since $c∈R$ , then $c^2∈R$,.....

STOP!

Stop right there.  $c^2 = a+ bi \in \mathbb R$.

Don't say another word.  You are done.